# How to use have only one instance of a class in python

Tags: python, class, instance

I can already tell that this question will be disliked and probably answered really quickly. Id like to preface this by letting you know that i have research this, but cant comprehend what to do.

So i have a python script that creates a game of cards. The card game in mind is 3's. A game that only (to my knowledge) my family knows how to play.

My script thus far is:

```
import math
import random
from itertools import product

def start_game():
    print ("Game started")
    deck = Deck()
    deck.current_turn = random.randint(1,2)
    print ("Player " + str(deck.current_turn) + " will go first.")
    Round_Start()
def Round_Start():
    deck = Deck()
    p1down = Player1Down()
    p2down = Player2Down()
    p1up = Player1Up()
    p2up = Player2Up()
    if p1down.hidden == True:
        print("P1: " + " - ".join(map(str,p1up.cards)))
        print("P1: #/# - #/# - #/#")
    else:
        print("P1: " + " - ".join(map(str,p1up.cards)))
        print("P1: " + " - ".join(map(str,p1down.cards)))
    if p2down.hidden == True:
        print("P2: " + " - ".join(map(str,p2up.cards)))
        print("P2: #/# - #/# - #/#")
    else:
        print("P2: " + " - ".join(map(str,p2up.cards)))
        print("P2: " + " - ".join(map(str,p2down.cards)))
    Give_Turn()
def P1Turn():
    print("It is now Player 1's turn.")
def P2Turn():
    print("It is now Player 2's turn.")
def Give_Turn():
    deck = Deck()
    print(deck.current_turn)
    if deck.current_turn == 2:
        print("It is now Player 1's turn.")
        P1Turn()
    elif deck.current_turn == 1:
        print("It is now Player 2's turn.")
        P2Turn()
class Player1Down(object):
    def __init__(self):
        deck = Deck()
        self.cards = deck.Deal(3)
        self.hidden = True
class Player2Down(object):
    def __init__(self):
        deck = Deck()
        self.cards = deck.Deal(3)
        self.hidden = True
class Player1Up(object):
    def __init__(self):
        deck = Deck()
        self.cards = deck.Deal(3)
class Player2Up(object):
    def __init__(self):
        deck = Deck()
        self.cards = deck.Deal(3)
class Deck(object):
    current_turn = 0
    def __init__(self, ranks=None, suits=None):

        if ranks is None:
            ranks = range(2,15)
        if suits is None:
            suits = ["H","D","C","S"]
        self.deck = []
        for r in ranks:
            for s in suits:
                self.deck.append(Card(r,s))
    def Deal(self, n):
        return random.sample(self.deck,n)

class Card(object):
    FACES = {11: 'J', 12: 'Q', 13: 'K', 14: 'A'}
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        value = self.FACES.get(self.rank, self.rank)
        return "{0}/{1}".format(value, self.suit)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.rank < other.rank
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_game()
```

Now some of the script is a direct copy paste from another users work, it was the only way i could get things to work up until this point.

My problem is that the

```
deck.current_turn
```

keeps resetting to 0. I figure this is because i have multiple instances of the Deck() class opened. But i do not know how to fix this.

My output from the current script is:

```
Game started
Player 2 will go first.
P1: 7/H - 9/H - J/H
P1: #/# - #/# - #/#
P2: 5/H - 3/S - 10/H
P2: #/# - #/# - #/#
0
```

This is my first Stack Exchange post, and I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Create the `Deck` once at the start of the game, and then pass it as a `deck` variable to every function.  After all, in real life, you wouldn't buy a new deck from the game shop at every turn of the game, would you?  No need to invoke the dreaded singletons, which would be bad idea anyway because then you can't run multiple games in one program.

Comment: Yup, every time you create a new `Deck()` instance, the current turn will be 0. Just create one `Deck` instance when you start the game, and then deal with it internally. Could even create a new class like `Game`, and instantiate a `Deck` in the __init__ method. That way you could just reference self.deck throughout the game.

Comment: I have combined the answers given by Rufflewind and Reptilicus to find a solution. I created a class called 'Game' and from there i have instantiated 'Deck' just one and referenced it throughout the rest of the 'Game' class. Works a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The solutions proposed in comments are much better, but the quick and dirty approaches are `Singleton` and `Borg`.

The Singleton way:

```
class Deck(object):
    _deck = None
    def __new__(cls, *a, **k):
        if not cls._deck:
            cls._deck = object.__new__(cls, *a, **k)
        return cls._deck
    # and the rest as you have it above
```

The Borg way:

```
class Deck(object):
    _dict = {}
    def __init__(self, ranks=None, suits=None):
        self.__dict__ = self._dict
        # and the rest as you have it, inc. the rest of __init__
```

They both work.  As the original inventor of `Borg`, I have a soft spot for it, of course, and you can still read my ancient essay about it at http://www.aleax.it/Python/5ep.html .